# Why do <Input/> and <button> not inherit in CSS?

Tags: css, inheritance, dom, button, input

I have found this is a problem - and I find that may people have asked the same / similar question - which gets the same set of answers:

1. Add 'inherit':`button {font-size: inherit}`
2. Set global: `* {font-size: 2em}`(which doesn't work with em, because scaling is inherited, so must use rem)
3. Declare explicitly: `body, button, input {font-size: 2em}`

This 'solutions' are a tad 'hacky', push the limits of best practice, but there is a gap in the [inheritance rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inheritance) I would like to understand.

I never come across the problem before because "who does this?', I have never had need for font-size inheritance on inputs and buttons before, until I was working through the excellent [WebDevSimplified Free React Hook Course, useImperativeHandle section](https://courses.webdevsimplified.com/products/home).

I thought this might be because  is a '[void element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element)', but  isn't void.

So, I can style inputs and buttons, but can anyone please point me to the reason why they don't inherit?

Google Search
MDN researach
StackOverflow trawl

I was expecting to find and answer "Input and buttons don't inherit css style because..."

Comment: can you post a [mcve] so we can see the issue?

Comment: @Sfili_81 did you read the question? not every question need an MRE

Comment: I can only guess here, that you are probably struggling with the formatting applied by the _user-agent stylesheet_ ...? Both Chrome and Firefox appear to apply `font-size: ;`, which I suppose would "break" inheritance.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif - I'm not sure that many read the question carefully - and it's currently rated -2, with is a stackOverflow badge on honour.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for taking the trouble to add a note on html input tag. As I mentioned, I was working in React, which I'm sure you know, does require closing tags for JSX: https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx#2-close-all-the-tags

Answer (score 1):

Browsers apply default styles to buttons (and other elements) so inheritance play no role here.

[image]

> When **no value for an inherited property has been specified** on an element, the element gets the computed value of that property on its parent element. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inheritance#inherited_properties)</sup>

The browser specified a value so no more inheritance unless you override this behavior using one of the codes you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks - It's almost the inverse - If a default value has been specified, no value can be inherited. - I was hoping this would be specified, rather than guessing.

Having looked through - I can only assume it's implicit - but I can't find it on any user agent style sheet copies - In the standards, some font sizes are explicit , therefore implicitly barred from inheritence, for example: headings.